# How to use looping in selenium webdriver java when every next generated element will have different names

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

[UI Project](https://imageshack.com/i/n1eln6p)

The scenario of the image above is the user can fill in all the details per partner, the user can add a maximum of 20 partners by clicking the add partner button, every time the user will add a new partner details the webpage elements will generate a new elements for example:

given name textbox for partner 1 is = partner[0][person][given_name] .

if the user adds another set of partner details the element for partner 2 given name will be:

given name textbox for partner 2 is = partner[[1](https://imageshack.com/i/n1eln6p)][person][given_name] .

so every time the user adds a partner details the index for elements will increment.

Here is my code im using selenium webdriver using java and hybrid automation framework. I want to use looping on this code, is it possible to use looping in this kind of framework? cause if i don't have to use loop, i have to write my action class like 20 times and i will need to find all the elements for each partner which is not logical thing to do. Please guide me. on how to make these code easier specially on making my code shorter.

// Here's my Page Object repository (its where i store my web page elements) 
// I have put a parameter (value) on my elements index

```
public class RegistrationPage extends BaseClass {

    private static WebElement element;

    public RegistrationPage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

  public static WebElement txtbx_GivenName(int value){
     try{

     element = driver.findElement(By.name("partner["+value+"][person][given_name]"));
     Log.info("Given name textbox found");
     }catch (Exception e){
     Log.error("Given name textbox is not found on the Register Page");
     throw(e);
 }
     return element;
 } 

 public static WebElement txtbx_LastName(int value){
     try{
     element = driver.findElement(By.name("partner["+value+"][person][last_name]"));
     Log.info("Last name textbox found");
     }catch (Exception e){
     Log.error("Last name textbox is not found on the Register Page");
     throw(e);
     }
     return element;
 } 

 public static WebElement txtbx_Email(int value){
     try{
     element = driver.findElement(By.name("partner["+value+"][person][email]"));
     Log.info("Email textbox found");
     }catch (Exception e){
     Log.error("Email textbox is not found on the Register Page");
     throw(e);
     }
     return element;
 } 

 public static WebElement txtbx_ContactNumber(int value){
     try{
     element = driver.findElement(By.name("partner["+value+"][contact_number]"));
     Log.info("Contact number textbox found");
     }catch (Exception e){
     Log.error("Contact number textbox is not found on the Register Page");
     throw (e);
     }
     return element;
 }
```

// and so on.. for other fields

Here is my action class (its where i put my action script and you will also see in this section is where i get my data, i get my data from excel)

```
public class RegisterPartnerDetails_Action {

    public static void Execute (int iTestCaseRow) throws Exception {

       int val = 0;
        String sGivenName = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow, Constant.COL_GIVEN_NAME);
        Log.info("Given name picked from Excel is " + sGivenName);     
        com.businessname.pageobjects.RegistrationPage.txtbx_GivenName(val).sendKeys(sGivenName);
        Log.info("Given name entered in the Given name text box");

        String sLastName = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow, Constant.COL_LAST_NAME);
        Log.info("Last name picked from Excel is " + sLastName);
        com.businessname.pageobjects.RegistrationPage.txtbx_LastName(val).sendKeys(sLastName);
        Log.info("Last name entered in the Lastname text box");

        String sEmail = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow, Constant.COL_EMAIL);
        Log.info("email picked from Excel is " + sEmail);
        com.businessname.pageobjects.RegistrationPage.txtbx_Email(val).sendKeys(sEmail);
        Log.info("Email entered in the email text box");

        String sContactNumber = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow, Constant.COL_CONTACT_NUMBER);
        Log.info("Contactnumber picked from Excel is " + sContactNumber);
    com.businessname.pageobjects.RegistrationPage.txtbx_ContactNumber(val).sendKeys(sContactNumber);
        Log.info("Contact number entered in the contact number text box");
        //etc for other details
 val++;
```

}
    }

I'm using also modular framework, its where my main class is located. Correct me if im wrong im thinking that i will put my for loop here right?

```
@Test
  public void main() throws Exception {

     com.businessname.modules.SearchBusinessname_Action.Execute(iTestCaseRow);
     com.businessname.modules.InputAustralianBusinessNumber_Action.Execute(iTestCaseRow) 

// Here is the registration script part, i will need to put for loop on this right?

     com.businessname.modules.RegisterPartnerDetails_Action.Execute(iTestCaseRow);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

possible solution will be passing the partner value as a parameter, since you use page obj repository this will be a better approach,

```
public static WebElement txtbx_GivenName(int value){
try{
element = driver.findElement(By.name("partner["+value+"][person][given_name]"));
Log.info("Given name textbox found");
}catch (Exception e){
Log.error("Given name textbox is not found on the Register Page");
throw(e);
}
return element;
}
```

And pass the value as 0, and increment it after adding new partner to the users.

```
int val=0; //initialize a variable
com.businessname.pageobjects.RegistrationPage.txtbx_GivenName(val).sendKeys(sGivenName);
//add a new partner
val++; //increment the value
```

Comment: thanks sir vignesh for the quick response, i will try this and post my results.

Comment: I tried this and it does not go to the second partner, its just stops at one partner.

Answer (score -1):

In case if loop doesn't work my solution is as follows:

1) Create an xml suppose name is "abc.xml" file which will contain all of the predictable ids could be as

```
    <dynamicid>
<id>
<textboxid>
partner[0][person][given_name]
</textboxid>
</id>
<id>
<textboxid>
partner[1][person][given_name]
</textboxid>
</id>
....
....
<id>
<textboxid>
partner[20][person][given_name]
</textboxid>
</id>
....
....
</dynamicid>
```

2) after that parse the xml as

```
        File file = new File(abc_xml); 
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document document = db.parse(file);
                    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    NodeList emailNodeElementList = document.getElementsByTagName("id");
          for(int j=0;j<emailNodeElementList.getLength(); j++)//loop for the multiple data
                    {       
                      //parsing the xml
                          Node nNode = emailNodeElementList.item(j);
                          Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                          //Now we get the values from the xml
                          String Textboxid=eElement.getElementsByTagName("textboxid").item(0).getTextContent();
    WebElement xyz=driver.findElements(By.cssselector("input[name='+Textboxid+']")).sendkeys("abcdef");
}
```

Hope this will help you.

please note that I have an interface from where I am getting the interface name example:

```
    public interface interface1 
{

    String abcde   =  "Foldername/nameofxmlfile";
    }
```

There are various ways to parse Xml you can view at
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Comment: This approach might involve more work when using the page obj repository

Comment: Yes, true it requires sound coding knowledge to make it reusable but it is robust and will work in every condition.

Comment: This is also great, i will also look into this approach. Thanks for the advise sir Abhinav